# Windows Server 2012 log out trigger

Tags: powershell, triggers, logout, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to set up a Windows Server 2012 log out trigger to run my Powershell script, which sends an information about freeing up an account on the server. For logging in, I used Task Schedule and I created a task for each user, but apparently, there is no option to set up a trigger on a logout. Is there any option to do it? Also, keep in mind that the trigger should work for each exact user, so trigger on Windows log out event doesn't really work, as it doesn't distinguish which user logged out - the script would be triggered on any logout.

Comment: Did you try [Group policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn789196(v=ws.11)#how-to-assign-user-logoff-scripts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the GPO to run a script every time there is a login, or logoff.

To do this Start> Run > gpedit.msc> Find User Configuration > Windows Settings > Scripts (Logon/Logoff) > Logoff.

Will be triggered every time a user logs off.

[gpedit.msc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzmn6.png)

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to choose only particular users to trigger it on logoff?

Comment: Not that I am aware of right this second, however in your script you can have it validate which user it is and decide to run or not as a workaround.